# Is there any way in Adyen to do online pre-authorization without handling the payment details?

Tags: adyen

The [Adyen pre-authorization documentation](https://docs.adyen.com/online-payments/adjust-authorisation/adjust-with-preauth) for online payments says before starting you need to "build an integration that can make a payment."

Can this integration be built using the Web drop-in/Components/Hosted Checkout integrations/ something else? Or is the only way to achieve this through using the Web API and [retrieve the shopper's payment details](https://docs.adyen.com/online-payments/build-your-integration/?platform=Web&integration=API%20only&version=71#collect-shopper-details)?

We want to avoid handling payment details in order to avoid higher levels of PCI compliance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That's possible using the Web drop-in and the [Advanced Flow](https://docs.adyen.com/online-payments/build-your-integration/additional-use-cases/): implementing the Advanced Flow allows to customise and perform the pre-authorisation (initial payment) while the Drop-in takes care of managing the card details.

On GitHub [adyen-examples](https://github.com/adyen-examples) there are 2 pre-authorisation examples (Node, .NET) that shows how to use the Drop-in to make the initial payment and then the backend to adjust/extend/capture the pre-authorisation.

Comment: Ah great. The advanced method encrypts the payment method details before sharing it with the backend which can then set the parameters on the `/payment` call set up pre-authorization. This doc also says that using the advanced flow will only require PCI SAQ A: https://docs.adyen.com/online-payments/build-your-integration/additional-use-cases/advanced-flow-integration/?programming_language=py&platform=Web&integration=Drop-in&version=5.55.1#testing-your-integration